# Bootstrap v4 Dropdown menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Idk why but I'm using bootstrap v4 and the drop down menu, literally copy and pasted from the documentation, doesn't work. I've also tried other peoples examples on blank pages. Nothing.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-12">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown button
                        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're referencing Bootstrap with a relative link. Are you sure you have downloaded `bootstrap.js` and placed it in a folder called `scripts`? If so, where does this folder sit in relation to the file that you are trying to run Bootstrap from?

Comment: yes of course the4 scripts work. I've used some other jquery code above what I displayed and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have indeed downloaded and referenced the files correctly, your code above will work as expected. Note that you have referenced your files **relatively**, so they must be in a `scripts` folder at the same level as the file you are trying to run Bootstrap on.

The only required files are jQuery, Tether and Bootstrap.js. `popper.js` is unnecessary. In addition to the three required JavaScript files, you'll also probably want the Boostrap CSS file as well.

The JavaScript files should be referenced in the following order:

1. jQuery
2. Tether
3. Bootstrap's JavaScript component

It doesn't matter when you load Bootstrap's CSS.

This can be seen working in the following example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-12">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Feel free to build from this template.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm making this in visualstudio with a mobile simulation. That's why I'm linking things locally.

Comment: Here's what's weird. I have some other collapsing menus, they work perfectly. It's just the dropdown menu, I click it, and nothing happens.

Comment: Linking to the files locally is fine - assuming they're linked correctly. My answer gives a minimal, working template. Try copying that into your project and then simply replacing the links with your relative links. If it no longer works, then your links are the problem, and you need to include them in the project and reference them correctly. If the links aren't the problem, then you'll need to provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or divide and conquer to work out what is different between your project and my example.